# How to add image + iframe in fancybox-3.1.20

Tags: fancybox-3

I want to add image and also iframe with google adsense below the image in fancybox.

I have checked almost document of fancybox-3.1, but doesn't found proper solution that explain how to implement it.

Please check snapshot for details,
http://prntscr.com/fn8m83

Thanks in advance for help!!!

Comment: You could add adsense inside caption area, and you could increase bottom margin so it would be always visible.

Comment: @Janis
Thanks for reply, i have tried as suggested, but this overlap adsense on image. 
https://prnt.sc/fnjo58 

I want image & adsense both inside container, so want container size should calculated base on image & adsense size. 

Also one white line display when added adsense in caption area, i want to remove this too. 

One more thing, i also want to add print button. 

Can you provide some working code, so i can easily implement this?